# IF statement and return python

Tags: python, if-statement, return

I am trying to design a function that returns whether a or b is longer but I'm having a syntax error.

```
def get_longer(a:str, b:str):

    return a if len(a) >= len(b) else return b
```

I have tried with a print statement and it is working however I need it to work with a return statement.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not an if statement, it is a *conditional expression*. you can't *have any statements in a conditional expression*. Note, `print` isn't a statement, it is a function. You want `return a if len(a) >= len(b) else b`. Or just write out the full if-else statement

Comment: `max(a, b, key=len)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra `return` statement

```
def get_longer(a:str, b:str):
    return a if len(a) >= len(b) else b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
def get_longer(a:str, b:str) -> str:
    if (len(a) >= len(b)):
        return a
    else:
        return b
```